# MongoDB aggregate: unwind and keep roots as seperate documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to go from this document:

```js
{
  _id: 1,
  property: "a",
  children: [
    { _id: 2, property: "b" },
    { _id: 3, property: "c" }
  ]
}
```

to this:

```js
{ _id: 1, property: "a" }
{ _id: 2, property: "b" }
{ _id: 3, property: "c" }
```

using a MongoDB aggregate function. I have not found anything suitable. `$unwind` comes the closest, but doesn't quite lead to the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Aggregation framework:

- `$concatArrays` - to add new property from parent object to the **children** array
- `$project` - to return only **children** array
- `$unwind` - to unwind **children** array to multiple documents
- `$replaceRoot` - to replace to root of the document to the **children** property

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "children": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$children",
          [
            {
              "_id": "$_id",
              "property": "$property"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$children"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$children"
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4bO7_UCte42)